# When emailing many recipients, access email of the current recipient in mailer view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm using Action Mailer to send an email to a set of users... mail(to: [array_of_emails]...).

In the view I need to know the email address of the person who just opened the email for formatting a link. This of course is straight forward if I'm just emailing one user, but what's the best way to know which is the current user opening the email given multiple recipients?

Answer (score 1):

The approach you're asking for is not exactly possible. As Jared states, the same email, with the same `<a href>` links, goes to every recipient.

However, creating uniques for each user in a multi-recipient email is a common problem. A solution is outlined in the Rails Routing Guide: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources

Basically, add a special route to your Routes.rb that links to a controller action that redirects to the link that's relevant to the current user. For example, if you wanted to put a link to a user's profile page, you could add code as follows:

routes.rb:

```
get '/my_profile', to: 'users#my_profile'
```

users_controller.rb:

```
  def my_profile
    redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end
```

Of course, after clicking the link the user would see the url change to `example.com/users/42` or whatever their ID is, but if this is an issue you can work around it by adjusting your controller action.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I know, what you are asking is not possible. The email is "rendered" when it is sent, not when the user opens it. They're just viewing a static message.

One way to track opens is to include a small image (1px x 1px) and append a query string to the path. When the recipient opens the message, their email reader will render the email and make a request for the image URL including the query string. You can then intercept it, log which user the query string references, and then serve the image up. The email app and the user will be none the wiser.